# How to run tasks which are after assertion in Google dataform even if assertion results in rows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I have few tasks to be run after an assertion check and my assertion results in more than zero rows due to which it's status is failed. My tasks after the assertion are getting skipped due to this reason. How can I continue with the tasks even if assertion is success or failure?